# Where did facebook tools go?

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know what happened to the Facebook Tools page?
It seems to be missing with the recent API launch.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php

Comment: Someone in the fb dev forum stated that they are working on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the release of the new graph api and developer site, the test console has now been integrated into the documentation 
For ex check the method users.getLoggedInUser
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getLoggedInUser

Comment: Cool. I've been looking for a way to submit a FQL query - Found it at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query